# How do I assign an port to a domain on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, portforwarding

I have a google flask website running on my AWS ec2 instance on port 7000. So when I go to my public dns url with the port it takes me to my page. How can I assign this url and port to a single domain I have?

```
ec2-55-555-55-5.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7000
```

Comment: You don't.  DNS A or CNAME records are at the host level only. The port assignment happens when you configure an application service to use that port.  If you want to port forward from your instance, you'll need to create a service that does that.

Comment: I think you are misusing the word "domain". You were actually refering to an AWS EC2 instance right? If that is the case, then the answer provided by @Reza is correct.

Comment: You can't assign a domain to a port. You assign a domain to an IP address or another domain name. If you want people to be able to go to your website without specifying the port, then you would have to have it running on port 80 for http or 443 for https, which are the default ports when one isn't specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can add AWS EC2 to AWS LoadBalancer, and configure your LoadBalancer listening form 80 port to 7000 port. And your url need to use AWS LoadBalancer DNS name.

or you can use ip table.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.
Go to the security group of your EC2, and add port 7000 to inbound section.
Please check following image:

[Security group inbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Jh1.jpg)

Now you can try 
   ec2-55-555-55-5.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7000

and should be work.